# Is it possible to substitute "then" with brackets?

Tags: shell-script

I first learned how to code in a `C` language, and using

```
if ( code )
then 
code
fi
```

makes it really hard for me to read my code (don't ask why).
Is there a substitute for `then`?

Something like this:

```
if ( code ) {
 code
}
fi
```

Comment: The answers below might help, but if I might add, it is a very good idea to get used to syntax of different languages. If you want to find employment in software development, or devops or as a sysadmin for that matter, you are going to need to learn to recognize and use many different syntaxes. You will be more valuable to any employer by being as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no substitute, but you can use both if you really need the braces:

```
if true ; then {
    something
} fi
```

That uses an unnecessary explicitly-braced [command group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01) as the body of the [`then`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07) block. Any commands in the braces will just be executed in the current shell when the `then` runs, exactly as though the braces weren't there.

I wouldn't really recommend this style in general or for code that someone else will need to read, but it does give you the braces you want, and it'll do the trick if you're using an editor that requires braced blocks or something like that.

Comment: Here is another which is "not worth recommending" – braces galore: `{ if { [[ a == aa ]];};then { echo yes;};else { echo no;}; fi;}` – basically, when you use `bash` enough, the *standard*  syntax becomes familiar enough, so that it isn't much of an issue.

Answer (score 15):

You seem to be looking for the [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) (`csh`, `tcsh`, etc...). Be aware that [experts recommend against it for programming](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

I'm not sure whether or not the part that you consider to be unappealing is the fact that `then` is on the following line? If so, consider using the following style:

```
if condition; then
    stuff
fi
```

I have to admit that spelling statement names backwards like `fi` for `if` and `esac` for `case` (but not `elihw` for `while`!) is kind of quirky. But that's standard Bourne shell, the most portable shell syntax you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I don't find the `then` unappealing, it's just that my editor will highlight corresponding `{}` pairs, and that's useful for when I have some sort of error because then I can easily see all of my `if` statements and see if something went wrong.

Comment: Ah yes. That plus `vi`'s `%` command which jumps to the matching brace/parenthesis/bracket. I sympathize. I miss `vi`'s `%` command when programming in Python.

Comment: Have you tried the matchit vim plugin ? It supports the % jump for if/fi in bash and a lot of other blocks in a lot of other languages. See here - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39

Comment: @AmitKumar thanks for the tip. I'll have a look!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is easier on the eyes:

```
[ condition ] && {
   # statement 1
   # statment 2
   # ...
}
```

Other than that, just get used to it. Use the language's idioms.

Comment: But lose the usually unnecessary bashism and just use one set of brackets.

Answer (score 5):

The following is near to there. And weird.

```
: if; { code; } && {
    code
}
```

I personally never liked the...

```
if true; then
more;fi
```

...form myself. I like it when the control words *lead*. It always seemed strange to me that the prevailing `...;then` form came about at all.

```
if    this && that
then  do these things too
else  i will probably get upset
fi
```

It's almost entirely opposite to your request, but it's another way to do it. You can also tack any wanted redirects onto the `fi` line as needed and they will apply to the whole block.

Comment: This prevailing form seems to be just another incarnation of the common `if(...) {`, i.e. leaving opening brace on the same line as `if` in C-like languages.

Comment: @Ruslan - Perhaps - but the line doesn't actually make any difference at all in C, does it?

Comment: Right, but neither does the line break make a difference in shell, does it? The semicolon after condition already makes the interpreter look for continuation of the `if` command, even if on the next line.

Comment: @Ruslan - yeah - you have to use the `;` delim in that case. It's why they do.

Comment: Using the `:` shell builtin like this, just so a line of code could be byte-wise closer to C syntax, should not be encouraged in any way.

Comment: @JosipRodin - because you say so?

Comment: @mikeserv because it doesn't really make the script readable to people who speak only C, yet it makes it less readable to people who speak shell

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
[ "$var" = "find" ] && echo "found"
```

is equivalent to:

```
if [ "$var" = "find" ]; then
  echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: As he states in the question, he wants *brackets*. Put some `{...}` around the `echo "found"`, and then you'll be heading in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

I always use:

```
if (code); then
   code;
fi
```

Probably not exactly what you want but it's a bit more c like.

Comment: That causes a subshell, lowering performance.